# preforming a scroll view driven interactive transition

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer, uiscrollviewdelegate

In the apple music app there's a transition from the opened music player that is *seemingly* driven by the scroll views content offset as pictured below.

[image: screenshot]

Behavior: The scroll view behaves like normal up until it reaches a contentOffset of 0 then the transition begins. This transition can occur while the user pans or with a fast enough swipe leading into the transition.

While transitioning I've also noticed that the scroll view indicators height diminishes in relation with the transition completion.

The overall animation here is very fluid and I would like to replicate it as such.

I know how to preform the necessary animations, but I don't know exactly how they're driving it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "use the content offset to drive the transition". The transition doesn't start until the content offset is zero, and it stays at zero throughout the transition.

Comment: @matt  At first I thought it might be a parallax effect. Where it normally would bounce it stops and the velocity seamlessly carries into the transition.

Comment: But that is the _opposite_ of "the transition is driven by the scroll view's content offset". The scroll view isn't scrolling at all during the transition. The scroll view reaches zero, they turn off scrolling entirely. The transition is driven by the user's finger, directly; we are now "dragging" the whole view instead of just the scroll view.

Comment: @matt I've tried that. I don't think they're disabling scrolling since the scroll indicator remains visible. I tried holding the content offset at 0 while using the translation value of the gesture to drive an animation but I can't seem to do the handoff correctly if that makes sense

Comment: I see what you mean. The scroll indicator gets smaller as we drag down. It's almost as if the whole _view_ is actually inside another scroll view, and what we are experiencing is the "bounce" — that's why it snaps back like that when you let go.

Comment: @matt yes, that effect threw me off a little. Sorry about for the unclear question above. I'll edit it a little.

Comment: It appears like the transition starts only after the user takes the finger off. Might be worth detecting when the finger is taken off and if the scroll offset had crossed a threshold when the finger is taken off. If so start animation to push the view down

Comment: "It appears like the transition starts only after the user takes the finger off" Agreed, that's why I said it looked like until then we were just scrolling some more within the "bounce" of some out scroll view I can't see. — I'd be curious whether you could emulate this just by putting a vertical scroll view in a vertical scroll view...?

Comment: @user1046037 If you look in app at the view under the player, as soon as the scroll view reaches contentOffset of 0 it begins to transform the underlying view which leads me to believe that the transition begins as soon as it reaches that point. So when the pan gesture ends, the transition continues to it's final state depending on the completion percentage. Also in app try swiping instead of panning you'll notice that the transitions completion percentage directly relates to the speed at which you swiped.

Comment: Ok break into series of step and try one by one. Then you would have a more specific problem. Also have a look at `UIScrollViewDelegate` ( like `scrollViewDidEndScrolling`) to detect various events in a scroll view